# Error in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when Angular request to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, angular, ruby-on-rails-4, jsonapi-resources

I'm using Angular 2 to make an API(rails) request. When I make the http request through angular, I get the following error:
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api-url. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
 However, if I try to make a request through Postman or the browser itself, I don't get any error. The data is displayed normally
angular code:

```
makeRequest() {
  let user = {"user": "user", "password": "password"};
  let headers: Headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(user.user + ':'+user.password));
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/vn.api+json')
  let this.http.get(api-url, {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
  this.data = data;
  })
 }
```

In my rails server i using the gem 'jsonapi-resources'to open AP. In my api controller, i have this code to authenticate and set headers to requests:

```
module Api
  class ApiController < JSONAPI::ResourceController
    prepend_before_action :set_headers, :authenticate

    def context
      { current_station: @user }
    end

    private

    def authenticate
      authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |token, _|
      @user = User.where(api_key: token).first
      end
    end

    def set_headers
      response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    end
  end
end
```

When i make request in browser or using postaman, the header appears normally, but in Angular i have the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Long story short, browsers forbid by default one domain (http://localhost:4200) to make AJAX requests to another one (http://api-url). It works in "postman" because this is an extension and then, the CORS does not apply. If you want to fix this issue, you have to configure your server to returns certain header saying to the client that it allows the CORS connection.

In fact, when a website is trying to make an AJAX request to another domain, it first send an `OPTION` request to ask what are the domain allowed. This list is returned by the server via the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. For example, it could contain a star ("*") to indicate that anyone could make AJAX call to this server. If this header allows your client to make AJAX call, your actual request will be executed, otherwise, you'll get an error (probably the one you currently get)